# C#: get-content -Encoding Byte from Powershell

Tags: c#, powershell

does anyone know the C# equivalent to powershells "get-content -Encoding Byte" ?

I would like transorm this:

```
Get-Content  $m1,$m2,$m3 -Enc Byte -Read 512 | Set-Content $m4 -Enc Byte
```

into c# code, without invoke a powershell process.

Comment: In its current form, your question can only be answered by people who know *both* Powershell and C#, or are willing to do research about them. If you could describe what you're trying to achieve - what `Get-Content` does, and what the `-Enc Byte` parameter means - it would be *much* easier to help you. (What are `m1`, `m2` and `m3`, as well?)

Comment: Hey Jon, it concats files in a binary way, these $m are path-strings . in my case i want to pack some files for a 7zip silent install. thanks for your comment.

Comment: a commandline equivalent would be copy /b "%~dp0\7zip\7zSd.sfx" + "%~dp0\7zip\config.txt" + "%~dp0\....."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string m1, m2, m3, m4;  // put some nice file paths in here

using (var m4Stream = File.Create(m4)) {
    using (var m1Stream = File.OpenRead(m1)) {
        m1Stream.CopyTo(m4Stream, 512);
    }
    using (var m2Stream = File.OpenRead(m2)) {
        m2Stream.CopyTo(m4Stream, 512);
    }
    using (var m3Stream = File.OpenRead(m3)) {
        m3Stream.CopyTo(m4Stream, 512);
    }
}
```

With slightly more effort this code can be generalized to take any number of input files, not exactly three. I've left in the buffer size of 512 to match the PowerShell code, but you're probably better off leaving that out, so `CopyTo` can use its own buffer size. In PowerShell this is a necessity because the pipeline will otherwise operate byte for byte, but `CopyTo` is not so naive.

Comment: Any reason for using `File.OpenWrite` rather than `File.Create` here? That would truncate for you

Comment: @JonSkeet: No reason, other than that I don't have all methods and overloads of `File` immediately resident in my head. Edited, thanks. (Actually, an even *better* approach is to `.SetLength` immediately to the size of the three files combined, since this speeds up the resulting copy and reduces fragmentation, but it would no longer be the equivalent of what the PowerShell command is doing.)